# Creating declarative MVC3 Razor Helper like Helper.BeginForm()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

[Creating MVC3 Razor Helper like Helper.BeginForm()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196276/creating-mvc3-razor-helper-like-helper-beginform)
says that it can be done using extension methods and implementing IDisposable. Can the same be done by using declarative Razor helpers eg. @helper SomeHelper(){}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of.
Razor helpers return raw HTML, not `IDisposable`, so you can't use it with `using`.

However, you can create a Razor helper in `App_Code` to render the content, then call it from a normal extension method that writes the content directly to the page and returns a separate `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 1):

No because helper.BeginForm() requires the IDisposable method to write out the closing `</form>` tag. As a razor helper is essentially a method and not a class it can't implement IDisposable.