# MVC3 Razor and Ajax.ActionLink without closing tag

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to render a lot of content inside ajax action link - between `<a ...>` and `</a>`.

**How can I render ajax action link without closing `</a>` tag?**

For example:

```
@Ajax.ActionLinkWithNoClosingTag(....)
  <image ... />
  <span ... />
  @Html.Partial(...)
</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "render a lot of content" ? Not that clear...

Comment: Please show some existing code. It's hard for me to tell, what you want to achieve.

Comment: Something like <image />, <span /> etc... I do not like the solution to put this content in a form of string, I want it to be a plain html...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you need a helper like the Helper.BeginForm() one. Maybe without the IDisposable feature, but with the hability of include other elements inside.
I recommend you to look to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196276/creating-mvc3-razor-helper-like-helper-beginform) and adapt it to your needs.