# Using-Statement in RazorEngine (without the HtmlHelper from MVC)

Tags: .net, razorengine

I'm using the RazorEngine without the MVC-Framework.
That means I don't have the HtmlHelper for creating templates.

That's fine, I don't need any methods from it anyway.
But I need to create my own methods like the BeginForm.

Now those are done with HtmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write, which I don't have.
Is there a "out of the box"-way to do that, or do I have to do some magic here?

Comment: Are you using [Web Pages Razor](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/aspnet-web-pages-(razor)-faq) or just the [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: I'm using the pure RazorEngine from the github-repository (so the second link)

Answer (score 12):

The [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) is designed with deriving your own types for use in the Engine itself.

First create your own Helpers:

```
public class RazorHtmlHelper
{
    public IEncodedString Partial(string viewName)
    {
        ITemplate template = RazorEngine.Razor.Resolve(viewName);

        ExecuteContext ec = new ExecuteContext();

        RawString result = new RawString(template.Run(ec));

        return result;
    }
}

public class RazorUrlHelper
{
    public string Encode(string url)
    {
        return System.Uri.EscapeUriString(url);
    }
}
```

Next create your own Template:

```
public class RazorTemplateBase<T> : TemplateBase<T>
{
    private RazorUrlHelper _urlHelper = new RazorUrlHelper();

    private RazorHtmlHelper _htmlHelper = new RazorHtmlHelper();

    public RazorUrlHelper Url
    {
        get
        {
            return this._urlHelper;
        }
    }

    public RazorHtmlHelper Html
    {
        get
        {
            return this._htmlHelper;
        }
    }
}
```

Before Parsing set your TemplateServiceConfiguration:

```
Razor.SetTemplateService(new TemplateService(
  new TemplateServiceConfiguration()
  {
    BaseTemplateType = typeof(RazorTemplateBase<>)
  };
));

result = RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(templateText, model);
```

Now the RazorEngine has `@Html.Partial()` and `@Url.Encode()` available in views.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's actually something I knew. But I don't know how to implement a function like BeginForm (with the IDisposable-interface).

Comment: So you're probably looking for [Creating MVC3 Razor Helper like Helper.BeginForm()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196276/creating-mvc3-razor-helper-like-helper-beginform).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this example is using the HTMLHelper which provdes ViewContext.Writer - which I don't have

Comment: Does not compile in RazorEngine 3.7.0 :(

Comment: @Anthony I love comments, but it would be really beneficial if you could include why.

Comment: Try it, the compilers answers will be more definitive than mine. There are notes here: https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/Upgrading.html
The RazorEngine.Razor.Parse has been renamed, that's the easy one. I don't have the code in front of me now, but the code in Partial() had to be started from scratch again.

Answer (score 0):

A much more simple fix (now) is to add the following to the top:

```
@using RazorEngine.Text
```

And then in your template use:

```
@(new RawString(Model.RawHtmlContents))
```

or

```
@(new RawString("<h3>This is custom <b>HTMLM/b></h3>"))
```