# Resolve html helper

Tags: c#, razorengine

I am using [Razor Engine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) to dynamically compiling my razor view from the database. Now im using **Razor Engine 3.7.3**. I saw few posting about how to read html helper and compile it, but it was for the old version of razor engine.

I have read about `ITemplateServiceConfiguration`, but i cant really understand how it works either.

***My question is, how can I runcompile() razorengine (v3.7.3) successfully with @Html (Html helper), @Url (Url Helper), and @section (like @Section Scripts, @Section featured) in the html content from my database?***

The things i have done so far. I tried to implement a code that i got from another post. The code was intended for older version of razor engine. He suggested that we create our own helper class:

```
public class RazorHtmlHelper
{
    public IEncodedString Partial(string viewName)
    {
        ITemplate template = RazorEngine.Razor.Resolve(viewName);

        ExecuteContext ec = new ExecuteContext();

        RawString result = new RawString(template.Run(ec));

        return result;
    }
}

public class RazorUrlHelper
{
    public string Encode(string url)
    {
        return System.Uri.EscapeUriString(url);
    }
}
```

And then he suggested to create our own templating:

```
public class RazorTemplateBase<T> : TemplateBase<T>
{
    private RazorUrlHelper _urlHelper = new RazorUrlHelper();

    private RazorHtmlHelper _htmlHelper = new RazorHtmlHelper();

    public RazorUrlHelper Url
    {
        get
        {
            return this._urlHelper;
        }
    }

    public RazorHtmlHelper Html
    {
        get
        {
            return this._htmlHelper;
        }
    }
}
```

And before parsing, we need to set our config:

```
Razor.SetTemplateService(new TemplateService( new TemplateServiceConfiguration()
{
    BaseTemplateType = typeof(RazorTemplateBase<>)
};
));

result = RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(templateText, model);
```

There is no problem with the RazorUrlHelper, but the RazorHtmlHelper cannot properly read these codes because it is deprecated:

```
ITemplate template = RazorEngine.Razor.Resolve(viewName);
ExecuteContext ec = new ExecuteContext();
RawString result = new RawString(template.Run(ec));
```

The codes above are from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047024/using-statement-in-razorengine-without-the-htmlhelper-from-mvc)

Comment: can you show what have you done so far?

SO that we can help you better

Comment: Ok i edited it, please review.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RazorEngine WebApiTemplateBase @Url.Content()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461041/razorengine-webapitemplatebase-url-content)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure that my suggestions will directly solve your problem.  In my professional experience trying to leverage deprecated classes does not yield positive results.  I personally would not try to render views directly from a database. If i was in your position leveraging razor view engine with MVC4 i would abandon your approach follow these steps.

1. Right click on your project and update MVC4 and all included js/dll/libraries to the latest version using nuget.
2. Create sets of Model objects that contain variables to house all information that you will be pulling from the database.  Leverage inheritance or design them in such a way that they are efficiently used on a request per request basis.
3. Build your main master and partial views for your MVC project that most efficiently prevent any duplicate front end code.  If these views are mainly going to return HTML responses, set your controller actions to an ActionResult() pointing to the master views for your application. Fill your model object with all of the data that it needs from the database in these controller actions and pass the filled model objects to your master view.
4. In your partial and master views, you can define this model object as the main model at the top of the view and pass the model variables as parameters to your HTMLHelpers.
5. Create your HTML Helper objects that take these model variables as parameters, and define their namespaces in your Views/web.config file.  In this example i used the namespace System.Web.HtmlHelpers. If you do not do this, you will not be able to leverage any custom helpers outside of the base namespaces in your views.

   ```
   <system.web.webPages.razor>
   <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
     <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
       <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.HtmlHelpers" />
      </namespaces>
     </pages>
   </system.web.webPages.razor>
   ```

   6. In your HTMLHelpers namespace classes, create MVCHtmlString or other MVC methods that take your database model parameters and translate them into working and functioning HTML/JSON or XML.  Reference these custom HTML helpers in your partial and master views.

If you implement your HTMLHelpers in this way, you are abstracting away your JIT compiled code (all view code) with the logic that accesses data and translates structured database data into viewable HTML. In the above example that you are presenting you will be JIT compiling most of the logic for your views at runtime which is very expensive in terms of performance.  MVC was designed in such a way so that you can prevent taking on all of that overhead.  If you create powerful HTML helpers that exist within pre-compiled libraries, you can make your view code extremely small and simple.