# Razor Optionally Wrap output

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have some html that I want to wrap with another tag optionally.

For instance, this would be an unread document:

```
<strong>
    <a href="viewDocument">
        View Document
    </a>
</strong>
```

And this would be a read document:

```
<a href="viewDocument">
    View Document
</a>
```

Is there an easier way to do this besides adding two `@if` Statements like so? This way is a bit clunky

```
@if(test)
{
    @:<strong>
}
    <a href="viewDocument">
        View Document
    </a>
@if(test)
{
    @:</strong>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26833747/526704) I adapted an optional wrapping HtmlHelper that I thought would be useful for others. This will wrap the html only if the provided `test` evaluates to true.

In your static class for Html Helpers:

```
public static IDisposable BeginOptionalWrap(this HtmlHelper helper, string tag, bool test, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var tb = new TagBuilder(tag);
    var attrs = GetAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    if (attrs != null)
    {
        tb.MergeAttributes(attrs);
    }
    if (test)
    {
        helper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
    }

    return new OptionalWrap(helper, tb, test);
}
```

The class:

```
public class OptionalWrap : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HtmlHelper _Helper;
    private readonly TagBuilder _Tag;
    private readonly bool _test;

    public OptionalWrap(HtmlHelper helper, TagBuilder tag, bool test)
    {
        _Helper = helper;
        _Tag = tag;
        _test = test;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_test)
        {
            _Helper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(_Tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@using(Html.BeginOptionalWrap("strong", Model.IsUnread, new { @class="someClass" })){
    <a href="viewDocument">
        View Document
    </a>
}
```